# zf2 How to save json return value to a variable

Tags: json, zend-framework2

i have this code to return json
`return new JsonModel(array(
    'id' => $id,
    'name' => 'ana',
    ));`

that code will return this
`{"id":"83493","name":"ana"}`
my question is how do i save id value to a variable. lets just say my variable is $a. How do i save 83493 to $a?

Comment: How do you cal it? Javascript/Ajax or via a Php call, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are returning the json array from a controller's action to a view file.

Was this action called via some ajax call? If yes then, on success of that ajax call, you will have something as -

```
$.ajax({
    .....
    .....
    .....
    success: function(data) {
        var a = data.id;        //Here variable a will have value as 83493
    },
});
```

As you are sending the array and not just a single value, the `data` parameter in the `success` function will act like a object and so `id` and `name` will become its properties.

Properties should be accessed via dot (.) operator Eg: `data.id and data.name`

I hope this is what you are expecting, please let us know if its not.